# How do I prove that $G$ is generated by two elements?

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification, proof-explanation

The question below is Exercise $1.12$ from [here](https://www3.nd.edu/~gconant/Math/Algebra_Exercises_List.pdf). I think I have an example that does not require $G$ to be generated by two elements. I do not know what the question is trying to ask if my solution is correct.

Let $G = \mathbb{Z}, H = 2\mathbb{Z}$. Then, $H \unlhd G$, and $H = \langle2\rangle$, so H is cyclic. Similarly, $G/H = \{2\mathbb{Z}, 1+2\mathbb{Z} \}$, which is also cyclic since it is an order $2$ group. But clearly, $G = \langle1\rangle$.

Is my solution wrong?

Comment: Well, G is generated by one element, but it's also generated by two elements.  I don't see where it says that a minimal generating set has two elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They mean "Prove that you can always find two elements $g,h\in G$ such that $G=\langle g,h\rangle$". There is no requirement that this is optimal. Cyclic groups can also be generated by two elements if you want. And clearly we have $G=\langle 2,3\rangle$ in your case.